# Initialize an std::array of tuples with curly braces

Tags: c++, c++11

This probably has a very simple answer, but I really can't figure it out. Why do I get errors for doing this? What's the correct way to initialize something like this?

```
std::array<std::tuple<int, std::string>, 3> tuples{
    {3, "a"},
    {7, "b"},
    {2, "c"}
};
```

---

On MSVC 2015, I get the following errors:

```
No suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "std::tuple<int, std::string>"
No suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char[2]" to "std::tuple<int, std::string>"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an outstanding issue with `tuple`. See, [its constructor in C++11/14 is `explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple). And therefore, it cannot participate in copy-list-initialization, which is what the inner braced-init-lists do (the outer ones are direct-list-initialization).

The idea was to [prevent you from being able to bypass a class's `explicit` constructors through `tuple`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3140.html). But, in C++17, this will be changed: if all of the tuple's types themselves are implicitly convertible from the respective given type, then so too will that constructor of `tuple`.

For your specific use case, you could use std::pair. Its constructor is never `explicit`.

Comment: So that's why the other guy's deleted answer actually worked before I posted. I thought that might've been doing something else I wasn't expecting. Guess I'll have to use a C array or just do it that way then. Ugh... C++17 can't come fast enough

Comment: @AlexYan: You could use `pair`, since your current type only has two memebers.

Comment: "_The idea was to prevent you from being able to bypass a class's explicit constructors through tuple_" Do you have a reference of where that was discussed?

Comment: Do you know what feature this is called? Just curious if there's any support for it on any of the current compilers

Comment: @AlexYan: I doubt this has a formal name. But [the most recent paper discussing it is N4387](http://wg21.link/N4387).

Comment: @black: Reference added.

Comment: More excited for C++17 or Star Wars VIII?